# How to loop though every column in MVC model and print the column name?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

In MVC 4 is it possible to loop though the @model object and print out the name of the column in the model giving preference to the `[Display(Name = "")]` tag first and if none is defined just displaying the text after the type declaration (i.e. `public string NameToDisplay`)?

Edit:
I am looking for a way to do this in a partial view using razor with out depending on another module like bootstrap or devexpress.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to interrogate the object and get all its properties. You would have to do this in your Controller and then pass the properties list down to your view.